# Windows 7, black screen, can't boot

Tags: windows-7, boot, bsod

After some research online, i found only solutions to Bsod that involve accessing safe modein windows / repair / other options that one can choose if after pressing F8/F5, the boot screen shows up. In my case it doesn't; what happened: my google chrome froze, i wanted to shut down the laptop, the command did not respond fast so i ended up closing the lid (acc to my setup, it puts the laptop into sleeping mode). When i wanted to turn on the laptop again, the black screen showed up with the cursor. Judging by the sounds the laptop makes, i think the windows is running normally in the background(it did not shutdown), but i cannot see and cannot boot. Did not do recent updates (to windows, drivers), i ran a virus check 2 weeks ago, but i don't exclude the possibility of malware. Graphic card is done? Do you have any suggested solutions? Many thanks!

Comment: Try pressing and holding your power button for 10 seconds. If this does not work then remove the battery, if your PC has a back-up battery inbuilt then you may need to wait several hours for this battery to run out.

Comment: @KevinAnthonyOppegaardRose it worked...all it needed apparently was a proper shutdown. Thank you!

Comment: no problem, glad it helped. I have made this an answer instead of a comment. Please mark my answer as the solution to your problem so this question is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a corrupted bootloader.
Here is a good step by step guide to fix it:
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/how-to-manually-repair-windows-7-boot-loader-problems/

If this doesn't solve it, try rebuilding the BCD.
Open Command Prompt (the above link shows how you can get to it), and enter the following commands sequentially as they are...

> ```
> bcdedit /export C:\BCD_Backup
> c:
> cd boot
> attrib bcd -s -h -r
> ren c:\boot\bcd bcd.old
> bootrec /RebuildBcd
> ```

In a nutshell, this backs up existing BCD in a new directory "BCD_Backup" and creates a fresh new one.

Source: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/927392

If this does the trick and Windows is back on, you might also want to run a few maintenance tasks just to be on the safe side.

Open Command Prompt and run these commands, the second one might take upto 15-30 min depending on the speed of your computer.

> ```
> chkdsk c: /f
> sfc /scannow
> ```

Comment: Thank you for the help, this is really useful knowledge for the future.

Comment: @Max, no problem, glad to be of help, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your display driver has crashed, closing the lid will not help unless that forces a shut down and from the wording off your question your laptop is not set up that way.

Pressing the power key for 10 seconds will force the laptop to shut down. If this does not work remove the battery (if you have a back-up battery then you will need to wait for that to empty).